# How to use opencv.js in capacitor's electron build ? ReferenceError: cv is not defined

Tags: typescript, opencv, ionic-framework, electron, capacitor

I'm facing an issue with opencv.js with my ionic capacitor app.

I put my opencv.js into `src/assets/lib/opencv.js` and I declare it like that in my ts file: `declare var cv: any` and in my main `index.html` I symply do   `<script src="./assets/lib/opencv.js"></script>`

It work well when i'm using `ionic serve` but when I'm running an `npx cap open electron` it doesn't work because of `ReferenceError: cv is not defined`

I tried to use typescript way to import the file like `import "./assets/lib/opencv.js"` or `import * as cv from "./assetS/lib/opencv.js"` but it doesn't work at all. Maybe I missing something with that way to import my file.

Do you have, please, some idea or things to try ?

Many thanks in advance.

**Edit :** I found the solution.

- Remove html import from index.html
- Add import cv  `'import cv from './../../assets/lib/opencv.js'` in your ts file
- Add async tag to your action button (mine was min rect method)

If you get error with "crypto" , "fs" , etc ... add :

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "crypto": false,
    ...
  }
```

Comment: have you tried `<script src="assets/lib/opencv.js"></script>`?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

- Remove html import from index.html
- Add import cv  `'import cv from './../../assets/lib/opencv.js'` in your ts file
- Add async tag to your action button (mine was min rect method)

If you get error with "crypto" , "fs" , etc ... add :

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "crypto": false,
    ...
  }
```